# Triggering touch event when object gets to a location where the player is holding the screen

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Basically, I am making a mini game where you have to catch snowflakes which are falling from the sky. Now, I want to make it so that when the user is holding the screen and once a snowflake gets to a location where user's finger is, it will trigger the touch event.

[image]

EDIT:
This is the code I got.

Snowflake spawns every few seconds. When it does, I simply add event listener to it.

```
function SnowflakeTouch(event)
    print("touched")
end
Snowflake:addEventListener("touch", SnowflakeTouch)
```

But yea, this doesn't work and I am interested if someone has another way.

Comment: and you are to lazy to read the documentation? or what is your problem?
Please add information on what you have tried so far to solve the problem on your own. Include some code samples and tell us what you expect the code to do and what it does instead. Maybe you could simply use collision? Put an object where your finger is and wait for the snowflake to  collide...

Comment: I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

The "Touch" event in Corona has more than one phase to it and you need to check for which state it is first [as you can find here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/touch/index.html). Anyway try this code:

```
function SnowflakeTouch(event)
    if (event.phase == "began") then
        print("touched")
    elseif (event.phase == "ended") then

    end
end
```